# How to implement Laravel forget password logic manually in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, logic, token

I want to support forget password logic in my website using **Laravel 5.2**

I don't want to relay on the out of the box code which comes with Laravel by default.

**my question :**
How to implement Laravel forget password logic manually? It will be good if you can give me steps to follow?

Comment: Just to be clear.....you want same functionality that laravel gives you out of the box, but write it on your own and asking for steps? If the anwser is yes....copy&paste laravel code to your own files and that's that....good job :)

Comment: Its like reinventing the wheel. Beside do you find anything inappropriate with it. May be that's not suited for your implementation. Glad if you could share.

Answer (score -1):

1.Built a forgot password form:

```
<h2>Reset Email</h2>
<form method="POST" role="form" action="{{url('auth/token')}}">
 {!! csrf_field() !!}
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Email Address" /><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send Reset link</button>
</form>
```

2.token() method in the controller:
Update the `remember_token` of the user with email provided. Email link to the user with that token and username as parameters. Here i am just returning the link

```
public function token(Request $request)
    {
        $token = str_shuffle('abcdefgh1234567890xsYsdsew');
        $getEmail=$request->get('email');
        $getModel=User::where(['email'=>$getEmail])->first();               
        if($getModel)
        {
            $getModel->remember_token=$token;
            $getModel->update();

            return '/auth/reset/'.$getModel->username.'/'.$token;
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/login')->with('message','Email doesnot exist!');
        }

    }
```

3.reset() method: If the token and username in the database matches the token and email in the link of email, redirect user to change form view.

```
public function reset($username, $token)
{           
    $getModel=User::where(['username'=>$username])->first();            
    if($getModel->remember_token==$token)
    {
            return View('auth.change', ['id' =>$getModel->id]); 
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect('/auth/forgot');    
    }
}
```

Reset Password Form:

```
<h2>Reset Password</h2>
<form method="POST" id="reset" role="form" action="{{url('/auth/change')}}">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
          <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password"  placeholder="New Password" /><br>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" name="cpassword"  placeholder="Confirm Password" /><br>
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change password</button>
 </form>
```

change() method:

```
public function change(Request $request)
    { 
        $getid=$request->get('id');
        $getModel=User::where(['id'=>$getid])->first();
        $password=Hash::make($request->get('password'));
        $getModel->password=$password;
        $getModel->update();
        return redirect('/auth/login')  
                ->with('message','Password changed!');
    }
```

**But I prefer built-in feature.**

Comment: Implementing authentication related code is not a trivial task, which is why using an established package is better than writing your own. Your code has a vulnerability. Once I am on the 'Reset Password Form' page, I can manipulate your hidden `id` input (which is the user id) and change the password for any other user based on id.

Comment: A second vulnerability is using `str_shuffle('abcdefgh1234567890xsYsdsew')` to generate an auth token. It would be fairly trivial for a unsophisticated attacker to detect a pattern and then attempt to brute force tokens. Going a step further, a sophisticated attacker could use the fact that `str_shuffle` is not a cryptographically secure randomness generator to predict token values.

Comment: @Bryan thanks for testing it and pointing these vulnerabilities. But i still don't get the first one. How is changing any other's password possible?

Comment: No problem @Sanzeeb, it took me a while to learn this stuff. Your `change()` is taking the `id` which gets passed in via the form (on the browser side) and queries the User model based on that, so an attacker can manipulate the form's html in their browser and change the hidden id to another user's id. To do it, an attacker would sign up for their own account, request a password reset, load the form, them modify it using something like Chrome dev tools, for instance.